# How to assign a line containing double quotes to a string variable in Java?

Tags: java

Sorry if this is a dumb question. Here is my problem. I have a String variable a. I need to assign the following line to a:

```
<td align="center" width="20%" ><a href="/listen/asid/
```

But when I use the following syntax:

```
a="<td align="center" width="20%" ><a href="/listen/asid/"
```

it doesn't work as Java confuses the double quotes inside the line for the start and end double quotes. How can I correctly do this? Thanks.

Comment: java uses the `\ ` character as an escape character.  put that before your `"` and it will do as you ask.

Comment: `I have a String variable a` Wait a minute you already have it in a variable then why do you need to create another String variable?

Comment: @anubhava It means he has declared a String variable a. ie: `String a;` It does not mean he has assigned anything to it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String a = "<td align=\"center\" width=\"20%\" ><a href=\"/listen/asid/";
```

\" Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.

Comment: Got it thanks. Had read about escape sequences in school books, now I know what it means :)

Answer (score 0):

Escape special characters:

```
String a = "<td align=\"center\" width=\"20%\" ><a href=\"/listen/asid/"
System.out.println(a);
```

The result will be

```
<td align="center" width="20%" ><a href="/listen/asid/
```

[Read more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: Why have you added the extra slashes? I can't have any extra characters in the string..

Comment: @user2213396 Please read article I mentioned in my answer, result string will not contain extra slashes, it is just a way to specify special characters inside string

Answer (score 0):

You should use the escape character for quotes - `\"`, and that will evaluate to a quote in your string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'escape' the `"` using `\`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

`a="<td align=\"center\" width=\"20%\" ><a href=\"/listen/asid/"`